# Solve $f(x)=(x^2+1)\sin(\alpha)+2x=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve $f(x)=(x^2+1)\sin(\alpha)+2x=0$

$1-) x= \sin (\alpha)-\cos(\alpha)$

$2-) x= \sin (\alpha)+\cos(\alpha)$

$3-) x= \cot (\alpha)+\dfrac{1}{\cos(\alpha)}$

$4-) x=-\dfrac{1}{ \sin (\alpha)}-\dfrac{1}{\tan(\alpha)}$

---

My Try :

$$f(x)=x^2 \sin (\alpha)+\sin(\alpha)+2x=0 \\
= \sin (\alpha)=-\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}$$

$x=\tan (\beta)$ then we have

$$\sin (\alpha)=-\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}=-\dfrac{2\tan (\beta)}{1+\tan^2 (\beta)}=-\sin(2\beta)$$

$$\sin(-\alpha)=\sin(2\beta)$$

Now what ?

Comment: Do you want to solve for $x$ or $\alpha$?

Answer (score 1):

The is a quadratic equation in $x$ and

$$x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2\alpha}}{\sin\alpha}=-\csc\alpha\pm\cot\alpha.$$